# Write Dataframe + Dynamic Filename to CSV with Output Path

Tags: python, csv, path, filenames

i know that the answer is simple and out there somewhere but i cannot seem to find it. As my title suggests, I am trying to write a pandas DF with a dynamic filename in .csv format to an output directory given a path. Here below is my error code below. *Thank you* for any suggestions and I'm open to doing this a different or pythonic way if possible.

```
runfile('C:/Users/U321103/.spyder-py3/Read_VORTEX_test_files.py', wdir='C:/Users/U321103/.spyder- 
py3')
klondikeii.Vortex_WIND.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\U321103\.spyder-py3\Read_VORTEX_test_files.py", line 29, in <module>
c.to_csv(Path(p + filename ), index=False)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'
```

My code looks like this:

```
from sys import exit
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

# Create a dataframe from csv
df = pd.read_csv("\\\porfiler03\\gtdshare\\VORTEX\\VALIDATION\\vortex_links.txt", delimiter=',')
# User list comprehension to create a list of lists from Dataframe rows
list_of_rows = [list(row) for row in df.values]
# Print list of lists i.e. rows
#print(list_of_rows)

var = df.variable.to_frame() #extract wind or power from df 'variable' column
#Find farm_data = farm_vortex cases
#for k in range(0,len(df)):
for k in range(0,1):
  if (( df.farm_data[k] == df.farm_vortex[k]) and var.variable[k] == 'wind'):
    #print('chinook = vortex data')
    c = pd.read_csv(df.link[k])#dataframe with vortex wind data
    filename = df.farm_data[k] + '.' + 'Vortex_WIND' + '.csv'
    print(filename)
    #save the data to a csv_file.
    p = Path('///porfiler03//gtdshare//')
    c.to_csv(Path(p + filename ), index=False)
exit()
```

Comment: `c.to_csv(p.joinpath(filename), index=False)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove Path() from '///porfiler03//gtdshare//'.

In p + filename you are trying to concatenate to create the full path. You can do so for two strings but not for a string and a path, and this is what the error is telling you.
Try:

```
p = '///porfiler03//gtdshare//'
c.to_csv(Path(p + filename ), index=False)
```